# How to add extra field to Woo Commerce checkout and display in edit order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I added three fields extra to my WooCommerce checkout (CVR nummer, reference nummer and ønsket leveringsdato). They show up correctly in the checkout but once the order is placed, the information is not sent to the WooCommerce backend/order overview. How do I send over the information so we receive it?

```html
    function add_woocommerce_billing_fields($billing_fields){

    //reorder woo my billing address form fields
    $billing_fields2['billing_first_name'] = $billing_fields['billing_first_name'];
    $billing_fields2['billing_last_name']  = $billing_fields['billing_last_name'];

    $billing_fields2['billing_vat'] = array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' =>  __('CVR nummer',  'keyelp-shop-customization' ),
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'required' => true,
        'clear' => true
    );

    $billing_fields2['billing_ref'] = array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' =>  __('Reference nummer',  'keyelp-shop-customization' ),
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'required' => false,
        'clear' => true
    );

    $billing_fields2['billing_date'] = array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' =>  __('Ønsket leveringsdato',  'keyelp-shop-customization' ),
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'required' => false,
        'clear' => true
    );
        
    $merged_billing_fields = $billing_fields2 + $billing_fields;

    return $merged_billing_fields;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` and `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address` action hook. code goes in your ative theme functions.php file.

> Using `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook you can
> save value meta.

```
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( $_POST['billing_vat'] ){ 
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_vat', esc_attr($_POST['billing_vat']) );
    }
    if ( $_POST['billing_ref'] ){ 
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_ref', esc_attr($_POST['billing_ref']) );
    }
    if ( $_POST['billing_date'] ){ 
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_date', esc_attr($_POST['billing_date']) );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
```

> Using `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address` hook
> you can display meta value after billing address.

```
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('CVR nummer').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_vat', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Reference nummer').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_ref', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Ønsket leveringsdato').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_date', true ) . '</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: How would you then make it also include it in the WooCommerce email that's sent out to us, so that we know what to pack etc?